# Posix shared memory vs mapped files

Tags: posix, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

Having learnt a bit about the subject, can anyone tell, what is the real difference between POSIX shared memory (shm_open) and POSIX mapped files (mmap)?

Both seems to use the /dev/tmpfs subsystem, rather then older IPC mechanism.

So is there any advantage of using mmap file over shared memory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The distinction is not always clear.  Shared memory can be implemented via memory mapped files.  [An excellent write on this can be found here (as applied to C/C++ programming).](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2044.html)

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that that shared memory is built on top of mapped files, but [This Page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/topic/apis/mmap.htm) seems to indicate that the ability to use memory mapped files as shared memory is conditional.

> The use of the mmap() function is restricted by the QSHRMEMCTL System Value. When this system value is 0, the mmap() function may not create a shared mapping having with PROT_WRITE capability. Essentially, this prevents the creation of a memory map that could alter the contents of the stream file being mapped. If the flags parameter indicated MAP_SHARED, the prot parameter specifies PROT_WRITE and the QSHRMEMCTL system value is 0, then the mmap() functions will fail and an error number of EACCES results.

Comment: Fairly certain QSHRMEMCTL is iSeries specific. There is no mention of it in http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/mmap.html for instance. Like so many questions about Unix apis, the answer really depends on which unix.

Comment: @Logan: fair enough, it did seem like an unreasonable restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Basically shared memory is an form of IPC.The shared region is created in /dev/shm which is created in memory only(RAM) and it requires no disk operations, hence it is a faster method of IPC.Although IPC can be done using disk file and then using mmap too, but it would be comparetively slow.Alternatively  you can always use MAP_ANONYMOUS with mmap which does not back up with any disk file.

Comment: How does MAP_ANONYMOUS lead to shared memory?

Comment: MAP_ANONYMOUS can lead to shared memory between related processes (children, grandchildren, etc. and the process that forked them).